# EC2: chef recipe: LoadError: cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-secretsmanager

Tags: chef-infra, aws-secrets-manager

I have installed  aws-sdk-secretsmanager gem using gem install inside ec2 instance and I can see gem is available, in my cookbook recipe I written `require 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager'` but its failing with compilation error.

Versions:

```
chef_version=16.2.73
platform=redhat7.9
```

Command:

```
gem install aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

Recipe:

```rb
require aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 2 resources updated in 10 seconds
Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
FATAL: LoadError: cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-secretsmanager
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue
thanks

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant snippet from your cookbook recipe? It will also help to know what you want to accomplish after installing that Gem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add this as answer even though the purpose of doing `require` inside a Chef recipe is not clear.

Chef maintains its own embedded Ruby (and Gems), and it is separate from the system-wide Ruby install. So the Gems installed by system Ruby will not available for embedded Ruby used by Chef.

It is usually installed in:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/
```

So `gem list` will be different from `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem list`.

So my first suggestion would be to install the Gems required for Chef using the embedded binary.

Writing pure Ruby code such as `require 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager'` inside recipes is not a standard practice. Recipes should contain [Chef resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource/) declarations. If the recipe depends on a gem, then it can be installed with [chef_gem](https://docs.chef.io/resources/chef_gem/) resource.

```rb
chef_gem 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the `aws-sdk-secretsmanager` gem using `chef_gem` chef resource to make the required `Gem` file available during Chef run compilation time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i am trying like below but its failing with had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 407 "Proxy Authentication Required"                          
    chef_gem 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager' do
          13:    compile_time true
          14:    action :install
          15:  end